# Whats wrong with my link?

Tags: php, anchor, echo

I am trying to echo a array value in a link, but it is coming up in dreamweaver as an error, but I cant work out what I have done wrong, can anyone tell me what is wrong with this line please ?.
thanks :-)

```
echo '<a href="index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=deletelead&token=echo $detail['cf_uid'];"></a>';
```

EDIT >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
THIS IS THE FULL CODE :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addemailtemplate");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo '<div class="namerow">';
    echo '<th>';
    echo $row->emailformname;
    echo '</th>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="messagerow">';
    echo '<th>';
    echo $row->emailformmessage;
    echo '<a href="index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=deletelead&token=echo        $detail[cf_uid]">dssd</a>';

    echo '<tr></tr>';
    echo '</div>';
}
echo '</th>';
mysql_free_result($result);
```

If I echo the cf_uid
    echo $row->cf_uid;
this works fine and displays the unique id for each record next to it in the table, I just need to take that id thats is being echo'd and put in at the end of the link so that it looks like http://link&token=2626382837728 << (cf_uid)

---

FIXED !
Thanks for everyone's help on this work, I worked out what was wrong in the end, what I thought was an array didn't appear to be, this code worked in the end >>

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addemailtemplate");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo '<div class="namerow">';
    echo '<th>';
    echo $row->emailformname;
    echo '</th>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="messagerow">';
    echo '<th>';
    echo $row->emailformmessage;
    $id = $row->cf_uid;
    echo '<a href="index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=deletelead&token=' . $id . '">LINK</a>';
    echo '<tr></tr>';
    echo '</div>';
}
echo '</th>';
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: remove single quotes and semicolon from $detail['cf_uid']; OR DO LIKE THIS 
echo '<a href="index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=deletelead&token=echo'. $detail['cf_uid'] .'"></a>';

Comment: this produces a link that is http://127.0.0.1:4001/chandlers/index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=deletelead&token=echo
but no cf_uid at the end.

Comment: If I remove the single quotes and semi colon I get http://127.0.0.1:4001/chandlers/index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=deletelead&token=echo%20$detail[cf_uid]

Comment: Oh! The question edited, I will read up again..

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate the strings and the variables.

```
echo '<a href="index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=deletelead&token=' . $detail['cf_uid'] . '"></a>';
```

update: If you get an error in this line the problem could be the line before!

Comment: This works, well as in it doesn't display an error any more, but at the end it says token=      and there is a blank space, it doesnt seemt to be echoing the cf_uid of that record.

Comment: Please try `var_dump($detail['cf_uid']);` for debugging.

Comment: Ok, I have just realised im using the wrong array name, it should be $row , if I change it to $row and use the above link I get the following >> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\server2go\server2go\htdocs\chandlers\components\com_chronoforms\libraries\includes\data_republish.php(24) : eval()'d code on line 376

Comment: That's why $row isn't an array. Make sure your query works. Next thing: You should check wether a value exists before echoing it `if(isset($row->emailformname)) echo $row->emailformname;`

Comment: I have edited the code at the top so you can see all the code, the weird thing is , is that it is echoing the data for the other fields just fine,  but if I try to include the cf_uid in a link it causes an error ? :-S

Comment: if I look in the database there is a cf_uid for each record

Comment: if I add echo $row->cf_uid; it echo's the unique id for each record just fine, I just need to echo that unique id in the link now where the 'cf_uid' part is

Comment: echo `<a href="index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=deletelead&token=' . $row->cf_uid . '"></a>';`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href=\"index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=deletelead&token=".$detail['cf_uid']."\">SOME NAME FOR THE LINK</a>";
```

[edit based on updated post]

Use this:

```
echo '<a href="index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=deletelead&token=' . $detail['cf_uid'] . '">dssd</a>';
```

However, I must ask... is there an array variable `$detail` which has a key `'cf_uid'`? And what syntax error are you getting (after you tried this)?

[edit based on comment]

Since it's `$row` and since it's an object:

```
echo '<a href="index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=deletelead&token=' . $row->cf_uid . '">dssd</a>';
```

Comment: What's the error? By the way, you need to provide a clickable object for your link. I updated the post. I also tried to emulate it. I got no error. More code before and after this `echo` command would help

Comment: It's better to use `"` and `'` instead of backslashing `\"`.

Comment: I was using the wrong array name, it should have been $row like the rest of the lines above it, the problem now is if I use $row I get the error Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\server2go\server2go\htdocs\chandlers\components\com_chronoforms\libraries\includes\data_republish.php(24) : eval()'d code on line 376

Comment: if I add echo $row->cf_uid; it echo's the unique id for each record just fine, I just need to echo that unique id in the link now where the 'cf_uid' part is

Comment: @IainSimpson, I updated my post. Let me know if the latest command works for you..

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can try this

```
echo '<a href="index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=deletelead&token='. $detail['cf_uid'].'"></a>';
```

This way you can just concat the string